# Override TextStyle color with foregroundColor - ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I'm trying to build a custom [Elevated Button](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) component : *(here is a simplified version)*

```
 ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) return Colors.green;
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Colors.yellow;
      return Colors.green;
    }),
  ),
  child: const Text(
    'Text Color needs to be foreground Color',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
)
```

for the needs of my App I need to provide a predefined `TextStyle` which will have a color

-> but I need this `TextStyle` `color` to be overridden within my Button by the `foregroundColor`

### Currently `Text` takes the `foregroundColor` **only** if I don't provide a color inside `TextStyle`

-> I need `foregroundColor` to always override my TextStyle color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Interestingly enough Valentin's approach didn't work for me, resolving `ButtonStyle(textStyle:`  with `MaterialStateProperty` failed to change my button text color*

*But what I realized thanks to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515274/12548494) is that :*

---

**As long you define your `TextStyle` inside `ButtonStyle()`** rather than inside your `Text()` widget

-> **`foregroundColor` will always override your `TextStyle` `color`**

Which means that if I write this :

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
      (states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Colors.yellow;
        return Colors.green;
      },
    ),
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
      const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text(
    'Text is now Green & Yellow on Press !',
  ),
);
```

My `Text` `color` will take `foregroundColor` & ignores the `color` I provide within `TextStyle()` which is what I was looking for !

Problem solved ⭐️

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the text style of your button, you can set the `textStyle` of `ButtonStyle` :

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      late final Color color;
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) color = Colors.green;
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) color = Colors.yellow;
      else color = Colors.green;
      return TextStyle(color: color);
    }),
  ),
  child: const Text(
    'Text Color needs to be foreground Color',
  ),
)
```

You can also reuse the foreground color of the current button style and set the text style with it:

```dart
 final theme = Theme.of(context);
 ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      late final Color color;
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) color = Colors.green;
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) color = Colors.yellow;
      else color = Colors.green;
      return TextStyle(color: theme.elevatedButtonTheme.style!.foregroundColor!.resolve(states));
    }),
  ),
  child: const Text(
    'Text Color needs to be foreground Color',
  ),
)
```

Comment: I'll upvote since you've helped me find a [solution to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515836/12548494) even thought it didn't work ; )